# Incorrect syntax near '-' in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

While I am executes the Stored procedures : 
    Exec [usp_SummaryReport] 77,1,'[Name]','2014-10-06 11:45:21.170','2014-10-06 11:45:21.170',[Name]
I am getting this error
    Incorrect syntax near '-'

Thank you all. I got it corrected. It's an issue with value passing.

Comment: `'[Name]'` doesn't seem right...

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the `exec` statement as posted. I would say that the error is arising from somewhere within the definition of `usp_SummaryReport`, as the values passed to it look very likely to be used in some sort of `sp_executesql` call.

Comment: Yeah - it's within the query. Likely a problem with now dates are handled and parsed as strings.

Comment: Very likely that they aren't quoted.

Comment: Very likely they're just concatenated into an SQL statement, aka SQL injection. You shouldn't get such syntax errors in a compiled procedure, *except* when you do dynamic SQL execution.

Answer (score 1):

As above suggested, please confirm that you create sqlscript dynamically and then execute?. If yes, then to solve just append this code before execute the script.

```
...... statement
    print @query
    EXEC sp_executesql @query
....
```

In SSMS, in message window, you can get the exact query witch give the issue. You can copy and past in new query window, modify it and finally replace in main sp's sql script.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is building up SQL dynamically by concatenating pieces of it.

You would not get this type of syntax error if you didn't because the procedure was syntax-checked when it was created. The only possibility left is for the procedure to create some SQL itself and try to execute it.

This SQL, built dynamically, is what is giving you this error. Without seeing the actual code it is impossible for us to say why this SQL gives you this error.

---

*Most likely* you are prone to SQL injection by trying to concatenate the dates directly into the SQL instead of using parameters, but we have no evidence of this.